# Using compression to get an external XML feed

Tags: php, xml, gzip

Using PHP, I am accessing an external URL, which is an XML feed file, and I'm parsing the results into my database. The XML file is large, around 27 MB.

How can I compress that file before the data transfer is initiated so I receive something much smaller than 27 MB? My guess is gzip should be used, but I don't know how.

This is my code I'm using for retreiving the data from the XML file:

```
$url = "http://www.website.com/feed.xml";
$xmlStr = file_get_contents("$url") or die("can't get file");
$xmlLinq = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);
```

EDIT: The file is already using default gzip/deflate compression, but I seem to be accessing the non-compressed one.

EDIT: I got this piece of code from the owner of the feed, those are supposed to be instructions how to solve this problem, but this seems to be in C#. I'd need the equivalent in PHP:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 60000;
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("gzip"))
responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
else if (response.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
responseStream = new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Do you have control over the server where the external URL is hosted? If not, you can't do something about the file

Comment: No, I don't have control. But apparently, the XML file is already gzipped, but I'm requesting the non-compressed version.

Comment: You need to make sure you're telling the web server that you support compression - have a look at the `Accept-Encoding` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment, web servers will only send content compressed using Gzip if the request's `Accept-Encoding` header contains `gzip`. To fire off a request containing this header, you can use the following:

```
$url = "http://www.website.com/feed.xml";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '', // specify that we accept all supported encoding types
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true));
$xml = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

if($xml === false) {
    die('Can\'t get file');
}

$xmlLinq = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

This uses the [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) extension, which is a very flexible library for making HTTP requests.

Comment: I couldn't say whether the feed was indeed received gzipped or not. Do you know of a way to check that?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be to put something like `var_dump(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD));` after the call to `curl_exec()`, and check that that number is less than the size of `feed.xml`.

Comment: You could also check the `Content-Encoding` header in the response.

Comment: I'm getting float(0) with the var_dump. I guess it didn't kick in.

Comment: That suggests that line isn't in the right place or the request failed - there's no way you downloaded 0 bytes of data :) You could always check the response headers instead.